# What is the most efficient way to store an array in SharedPreferences in Android?

Tags: android, arraylist, save, sharedpreferences

I need to store an array in shared prefs without the use of external libs like [Prefser](https://github.com/pwittchen/prefser) or [Hawk](https://github.com/orhanobut/hawk). Which I tried and found a lot of problems with both of them.

So my search led me to two different methods:

1. Using Sets:

   ```
   //Set the values
   Set<String> set = new HashSet<String>();
   set.addAll(listOfExistingScores);
   scoreEditor.putStringSet("key", set);
   scoreEditor.commit();

   //Retrieve the values
   Set<String> set = myScores.getStringSet("key", null);
   ```
2. Using String manipulation:

   ```
   //Set the values
   StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
   for (int i = 0; i < playlists.length; i++) {
       sb.append(playlists[i]).append(",");
   }
   prefsEditor.putString(PLAYLISTS, sb.toString());

   //Retrieve the values
   String[] playlists = playlist.split(",");
   ```

**The question:** What would be a more efficient way to do it when the order of the items does not matter and I have a big amount of items (say > 300)?

Comment: why aren't you using a DB? I normally don't use SharedPreferences for keys more than 30

Comment: @gmetax, you are right, usually, that's what I do also. But in this case, this is the only thing that I need to store and I didn't want to mess with DB implementation just for one single ArrayList.

Comment: I can't find the limit store of SharedPreferences but I don't believe that will be a good practice to store more than 1000 values on SharedPreferences

Comment: check that also https://stackoverflow.com/a/43080499/2401265

Comment: @EmilAdz, make a JSONArray and store it into SharedPreferences.

Comment: Actually SharedPreferences stored data in `xml` file then you put one key but >1000 value (although value contracted only one value). So key-value SharedPreference has no meaning. Have you considered using `file` to store your over 1000 value array?

Comment: Why not to try Realm? But i must say you need to read documents and spend time on it to figure it out how great it is.

Comment: @gmetax, I understand where you are going with it, but like I said for the sake of this argument lets say that I have 500 items and they will never exceed the storage limit. What would be a better way to store them in the SP without a DB.

Comment: @EmreAktürk, Like I said in the question I prefer not to use external libs at this stage.

Comment: then I believe the best option is 2. Even though that you will need time on 2 loops, I believe also on the core android will happen the same with `set` to be saved on the `xml` file of the `SharedPreferences`.

Comment: @Maddy, what is the difference between doing that and using a single string with manipulations, from an efficiency standpoint?

Comment: JSONArray will not be more efficient, but it would be "easier" to manipulate and readable

Comment: @EmilAdz, This is not an efficient solution, this is just a way to do your stuff. Even storing that much data in SharedPreferences will never be efficient.

Comment: Why dot directly use `File` ?

Answer (score 0):

The most efficient way would be store in a string via a ObjectSeializer.

A striing would loose the order of data but ObjectSerializer will remeber it. Here is a ObjectSerializer you can use:

```
import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.ObjectInputStream;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;
import java.io.Serializable;


public class ObjectSerializer {


public static String serialize(Serializable obj) throws IOException {
    if (obj == null) return "";
    try {
        ByteArrayOutputStream serialObj = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        ObjectOutputStream objStream = new ObjectOutputStream(serialObj);
        objStream.writeObject(obj);
        objStream.close();
        return encodeBytes(serialObj.toByteArray());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}

public static Object deserialize(String str) throws IOException {
    if (str == null || str.length() == 0) return null;
    try {
        ByteArrayInputStream serialObj = new ByteArrayInputStream(decodeBytes(str));
        ObjectInputStream objStream = new ObjectInputStream(serialObj);
        return objStream.readObject();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}

public static String encodeBytes(byte[] bytes) {
    StringBuffer strBuf = new StringBuffer();

    for (int i = 0; i < bytes.length; i++) {
        strBuf.append((char) (((bytes[i] >> 4) & 0xF) + ((int) 'a')));
        strBuf.append((char) (((bytes[i]) & 0xF) + ((int) 'a')));
    }

    return strBuf.toString();
}
public static byte[] decodeBytes(String str) {
    byte[] bytes = new byte[str.length() / 2];
    for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i+=2) {
        char c = str.charAt(i);
        bytes[i/2] = (byte) ((c - 'a') << 4);
        c = str.charAt(i+1);
        bytes[i/2] += (c - 'a');
    }
    return bytes;
}

}
```

and call via:

```
sharedpref.putString("data",ObjectSerializer.serialize(array1));
```

Comment: Why would using a string will lose the order? You are running on the array in order and appending items in order, split with save the order in which you appended the items.

Answer (score 0):

`JsonArray` helps you to convert and store

```
public static void putStringArray(Context context, String key, String[] array) {
    if (context == null) {
        return;
    }
    SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager
            .getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
    JSONArray mJSONArray = new JSONArray(Arrays.asList(array));
    editor.putString(key, String.valueOf(mJSONArray));
    editor.apply();
}

public static String[] getStringArray(String key, Context context) {
    if (context == null) {
        return null;
    }
    SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager
            .getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
    String[] stringArray = new String[0];
    try {
        JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(prefs.getString(key, ""));
        int len = jsonArray.length();
        stringArray = new String[len];

        for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
            try {
                stringArray[i] = jsonArray.getString(i);
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return stringArray;
}
```